# Convert a string to an xml file in android

Tags: android, xml, string

Can anybody tell me how to convert a string to an xml file in android?

Thanks

Comment: Is the string already in XML format and you want to create an in-memory object? Or do you want to output a string as part of a complete XML document?

Comment: yes string is already in xml .I want to be a xml document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [DOM](http://exampledepot.com/egs/javax.xml.parsers/BasicDom.html).

Answer (score 3):

The safest method is this:

```
Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory
    .newInstance()
    .newDocumentBuilder()
    .parse(
            new InputSource(
                    new StringReader(string)
            )
    );
```

Some people say you should close the StringReader, [but that doesn't have any practical benefit in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122013/should-i-close-a-stringreader).

There is another solution using ByteArrayInputStream:

```
Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory
    .newInstance()
    .newDocumentBuilder()
    .parse(
            new ByteArrayInputStream(
                    string.getBytes("UTF-8")
            )
    );
```

Make sure you explicitly specify encoding when using string.getBytes, [otherwise it uses the system default encoding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28%29), which could change depending on what platform you are running. Seems like UTF-8 is what the parse method wants, [but it's not in the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#parse%28java.io.InputStream%29).

Answer (score 0):

If the application is simple and doesn't need too much xml manipulation performance then DOM should do the trick. Otherwise try using SAX which can give a big boost in performance in certain occasions. Look at [this](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=28) tutorial that explains well the differences between them.