# Do I need to explicitly close the StreamReader in C# when using it with string variable?

Tags: c#

This is my code:

```
string data = "...";
var stream = new StreamReader(data);
```

Is that okay not call the `Close()` method?

Comment: It won't leak external resources, if you're talking about `StringReader` (which it seems like you are). See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122013/should-i-close-a-stringreader

Comment: It's always best to be consistent when working with IDisposable objects. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=VS.80%29.aspx - you should consider `using` to avoid memory leaks or keeping unmanaged resources in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you actually compiled and run your code?

**The [`StreamReader(string)` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ke0fzy.aspx) treats the input *as a file name!***

Unless this isn't really your code and you *meant* [`StringReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader.stringreader.aspx), your code is trying to stream the contents of the file name specified in `data`, which is likely to throw a `FileNotFoundException` because the file probably doesn't exist. And if it did, you would certainly need to call `Close` or integrate your code into a `using` statement to release the file handle.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, otherwise you will have a memory leak. Wrap your `StreamReader` in a [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) so you don't have to worry about cleaning it up e.g.

```
using (var reader = StreamReader(data))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to take a look at this tutorial on msdn:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056.aspx

which tells you about things you need to be careful with the `using` statement. Other than that, using is the way to go.

Another pretty [good article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6564/Understanding-the-using-statement-in-C) on codeProject. Worth reading.

Answer (score 0):

The resource will not be accessable to other processes until your process stops using it so you should close it if you don't need it