# How Do I Split A String By Line Break?

Tags: java, android

I'm a noob to android development and I am trying to split a string multiple times by its multiple line breaks.  the string I'm trying to split is pulled from a database query and is constructed like this:

```
public String getCoin() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_QUANTITY, KEY_OUNCES, KEY_VALUE };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";

    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
    int iQuantity = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_QUANTITY);
    int iOunces = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_OUNCES);
    int iValue = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_VALUE);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        result = result + /*c.getString(iRow) + " " +*/ c.getString(iName).substring(0, Math.min(18, c.getString(iName).length())) + "\n";
    }
    c.close();
    return result;
```

result.getCoin reads as this:

```
alphabravocharlie
```

I want to split the string at the line break and place each substring into a String Array. This is my current code:

```
String[] separated = result.split("\n");
      for (int i = 0; i < separated.length; i++) {
           chartnames.add("$." + separated[i] + " some text" ); 
           }
```

This gives me an output of:

```
"$.alpha
bravo
charlie some text"
```

instead of my desired output of:

```
"$.alpha some text, $.bravo some text, $.charlie some text"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You show output, without showing us the input, which does not help.

Comment: This means your input does not contain the `\n` character so the String isn't split. Check whether the input contains `\r\n` (if source comes from MS windows for ex.)

Comment: @JScoobyCed please check my edit I add \n to my string before i return result so it shout contain \n

Comment: Do you mean "$.alpha\nbravo\ncharlie some text"?  Because your existing output doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Yes. that's what I'm talking about.  How can i clarify my question?

Comment: I updated the question.  Make sure that's the correct unexpected output though.

Comment: Yes it is.  thanks for the edit.

Comment: I just tried constructing a `result` and then splitting it using your posted code and it worked perfectly well. Are you sure the code you posted is what's producing these results?

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454908/split-java-string-by-new-line

Answer (score 60, accepted):

you can split a string by line break by using the following statement :

```
   String textStr[] = yourString.split("\\r\\n|\\n|\\r");
```

Comment: That won't work for text from a Mac, where the line terminator is `\r`.

Comment: I think based on OS the terminator can be decided. The above solution will work only for windows IMO.

Comment: How about 
    yourString.split(System.lineSeparator());

Comment: @adn.911: `System.lineSeparator()` is platform-dependent, so you can use it only when you know, what line separator will be in your input.

Comment: Shorter: `"\r?\n|\r"`

Answer (score 19):

It's a little overkill, but you can use the standard I/O classes:

```
BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(result));
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String line = rdr.readLine(); line != null; line = rdr.readLine()) {
    lines.add(line);
}
rdr.close(); // good form to close streams, but unnecessary for StringReader

// lines now contains all the strings between line breaks of any type
```

The advantage of this is that `BufferedReader.readLine()` has all the logic worked out for detecting all sorts of line terminators.

As of Java 8, `BufferedReader` has a `lines()` method, so there's an easier way (thanks, @jaco0646):

```
List<String> lines = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(result))
                         .lines()
                         .collect(Collectors.toList();
```

or, if an array is needed instead:

```
String[] lines = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(result))
                     .lines()
                     .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: This is even simpler in Java 8, which added a [lines() method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#lines--).

Comment: Also note there's not a lot of benefit in [closing a StringReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122013/should-i-close-a-stringreader).

Comment: @jaco0646 - Yes, Java 8 does make it a bit easier. I'll update my answer to show that. Thanks. As to closing the `StringReader`, that was just me on autopilot (closing any stream once I'm done with it). I'm surprised I didn't stick the whole thing into a `try/finally` statement. :)

Answer (score 5):

Using the Apache commons helper class StringUtils.

The platform independent way:

`String[] lines = StringUtils.split(string, "\r\n");`

The platform dependent way. Maybe some CPU cycles faster. But I wouldn't expect it to matter.

`String[] lines = StringUtils.split(string, System.lineSeparator());`

Answer (score 2):

If possible I would suggest using the Guava Splitter and Joiner classes in preference to String.split.  But even then, it's important to make sure that you're properly escaping your regular expressions when declaring them.  I'm not certain "\n" won't be properly interpreted by the regex compiler in Java, but I'm not sure it will be either.

Covering all possible line endings is tricky, since multiple consecutive EOL markers can mess up your matching.  I would suggest

```
String [] separated = result.replaceAll("\\r", "").split("\\n");
```

Comment: I had no success with this. Should i just try to split by last character before line break or somthing like that?

Comment: If you had no success your input probably does not contain new lines.  Perhaps you could post the contents of `result.getBytes()'?

Comment: If you want to deal with all combinations of "\r" "\n" "\r\n" "\n\r" you can use: Splitter.on(CharMatcher.anyOf("\n\r")).omitEmptyStrings().split(yourstring); (note that this will also drop empty lines, which may or may not be what you want)

Answer (score 1):

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(^.+$)+", Pattern.MULTILINE).matcher(fieldContents);

while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("whole group " + m.group())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose the following snippet, which is compatiple with PC and Mac endline styles both.

```
String [] separated = result.replaceAll("\\r", "\\n")
   .replaceAll("\\n{2,}", "\\n")
   .split("\\n");
```

Comment: With this solution, blank lines in the input will disappear.