# Easy way of getting List<String> from String by splitting on EOL?

Tags: java

How do I get a `List<String>` from lines in `String`?   I want to handle `CRLF` (`\r\n`) and `LF` (`\n`) as EOLs.  Empty lines, including those trailing need to be preserved, so that I can use `String.join("\n", ...)` to get back the original `String` (however, I don't mind if `CRLF`s become `LF`s).

This is what I've come up with:

```
String x = "\r\n\r\na\nb\r\nc\n\r\n\n";

List<String> lines = Arrays.asList(org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.splitPreserveAllTokens(x.replace("\r", ""), "\n"));
```

I've seen [various](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454908/split-java-string-by-new-line) other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13464954/how-do-i-split-a-string-by-line-break) but they don't seem to require the *preserve empty lines* part.

Comment: String.split() destroys trailing lines.

Comment: `String.split` takes a regular expression, so you can handle both `CRLR` and `LF` easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with

```
String[] result = yourString.split("\r?\n", -1);
```

`-1` parameter is `limit` and it negative value means that trailing empty strings should not be removed from resulting `String[]` array (I am assuming that converting this array to `List<String>` is not big problem for you).

Comment: I don't know how `If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length.` translates to it working that way but it works!  The example in [String.split(String, int)][https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-] even had this!

Answer (score 3):

Use StringReader and Stream:

```
    String x = "\r\n\r\na\nb\r\nc\n\r\n\n";
    List<String> list = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(x))
        .lines()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to go with a regular expression that is needed by `String.split`, you could use the `readLine` method of a `BufferedReader`. An excerpt of its documentation:

> Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.

**Note, that it also splits on "\r" alone.**

So you would basically do the following:

```
String x = ...
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(x));
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    lines.add(line);
}
```

Note, with Java 8 it's easier:

```
String x = ...
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(x));
List<String> lines = reader.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 String[] lines = String.split("\\r\\n?\\n");

 LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();

 for(String s : lines) {
     list.add(s);
 }
```