# Closing InputStream and OutputStream

Tags: java, inputstream, outputstream

I read in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26541513/why-is-it-good-to-close-an-inputstream) that a low level file handled is allocated whenever fileinputstream or outputstream is used and hence it is always necessary to close io stream. In case of other streams(eg: ByteArrayInputStream) which do not deal with file or network io , is it necessary to close the streams? If so , why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will not closing a stringwriter cause a leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14542535/will-not-closing-a-stringwriter-cause-a-leak)

Comment: If you close *every* stream, you can never *not* close a stream. Worrying about which ones are which isn't a good use of your time.

Comment: @Oleg: The question specifically for `ByteArrayInputStream` is not answered by the Question you cite (but the answer is the same...)

Comment: @sruetti I think it's similar enough to be a duplicate. I've seen users with gold badges close questions claiming they are "effectively" duplicate that were much less similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I read in this post that a low level file handled is allocated whenever fileinputstream or outputstream is used and hence it is always necessary to close io stream.

A *file* input or output stream yes.  Other network streams must be closed as well because they have a file-descriptor.

> In case of other streams(eg: ByteArrayInputStream) which do not deal with file or network io , is it necessary to close the streams? If so , why?

Is it necessary, no, but's it's certainly a good practice.   If you look at the `close()` method in `ByteArrayInputStream` and `ByteArrayOutputStream`, you can see that it is a no-op:

```
public void close() throws IOException {
}
```

In terms of practice, if you get into the habit of *always* closing streams, then you will be better off if you switch later to use a different stream.  We copy code and patterns from one place in code to others so that doing the right thing and closing every stream may help later.

In Java 7+ you can use the try with resources to have the stream auto-closed:

```
try (OutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
    ...
}
```

Or you can use try/finally:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try {
    ...
} finally {
    baos.close();
}
byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
...
```

Comment: That's where try-finally gets dirty: Imho `baos.close();` should be enclosed in a `try {...} catch (IOException ioe) {//ignore}` as `close()` is declared to throw an `IOException`...

Comment: Typically I use the apache `IOUtils.closeQuietly(...)` which handles null streams and ignores `IOException` @sruetti.

Answer (score 4):

You generally **have to close** Streams, either explicitly (`Stream.close()`) or using try-with-resources, as described in the post you cite or in the article on javapractices.com @SassyRegards201 cites.

If you take your programming serious, **there's no "it usually works without"**. The only way you might get away without closing a stream is if it is **clearly documented** that the specific implementation does not need closing (as with [ByteArrayInputStream of Oracle JDK 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) and in the [OpenJDK code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.java#ByteArrayInputStream.close%28%29)) and you are **sure that only this implementation** is used. Changing the version or vendor of the JDK could void your assumption!

The problem is that you should **program against interfaces**. And as all streams implement the `Closeable` interface that defines the `close()` method (intended to be called to release resources), an implementation may change in a way that **might some day require** that you call the close method.

Closing every stream **doesn't cost much** (performance and developer time), is just **good practice** and nowadays checked by **bug finding software**.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't to explain it like him. Lol

Answer (score 0):

It's not absolutely necessary but it's a preferred practice like a lot of things in java.

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=8

Here's a link on which you can read up on streams and closing them and why they should be closed.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks @Sassy. I had a look at this link before I posted. It says , chained streams will be closed. However I wasn't sure why it had to be closed when none of the chained calls lead to a file or network io.

Comment: Ok so think of it this way. Think of your stream like a portal. And that portal can lead to one place but after that the connection closes. The portal can't have infinite connections.

Comment: You need to close the portals so you don't have leaks. So people aren't teleporting all over the place. I mean I think that's the best explanation I can give lol.

Comment: Ya np. Glad it helped ;)